# Microsoft Asp.Net 5 RC1

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to install `ASP.NET 5 RC1` but I can't because of an error on setup.

> Setup Failed
>
> One o more issues caused the setup to fail. please fix the issues and
>   then retry setup. for more information see the log file
>
> 0x80091007 - the value of hash is not correct

Log File:

```
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:41]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:41]i361: Created a system restore point.
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:41]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\moliv\AppData\Local\Temp\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\.be\AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\AspNet5.ENU.RC1.exe'
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, version: 1.0.11117.0
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i305: Verified acquired payload: SetupBlocked_Install at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\SetupBlocked_Install, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0cb88b2b-7b82-3890-96ab-deccbbb3a255\SetupBlocked.exe.
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i305: Verified acquired payload: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\2b825b3c-fe3f-3e14-b083-a41c0f8d1b22\Preparation.exe.
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, copy from: D:\Downloads\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:42]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'D:\Downloads\'
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:42]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, expected: BAEF7329894C48023E4E0F5F7D5C84E2243309F8, actual: FB0D8F2A91BEAC7991DC7A3FC13DA5F3D9E513C0
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:42]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:42]e310: Failed to verify payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:42]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:42]e314: Failed to cache payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 from working path: C:\Users\moliv\AppData\Local\Temp\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80091007.
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:42]e349: Application requested retry of payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, encountered error: 0x80091007. Retrying...
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:45]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, copy from: D:\Downloads\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:45]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, expected: BAEF7329894C48023E4E0F5F7D5C84E2243309F8, actual: FB0D8F2A91BEAC7991DC7A3FC13DA5F3D9E513C0
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:45]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:45]e310: Failed to verify payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:45]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:45]e314: Failed to cache payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 from working path: C:\Users\moliv\AppData\Local\Temp\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80091007.
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:45]e349: Application requested retry of payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, encountered error: 0x80091007. Retrying...
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i338: Acquiring package: DotNetVersionManager_x64, payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64, copy from: D:\Downloads\DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, expected: BAEF7329894C48023E4E0F5F7D5C84E2243309F8, actual: FB0D8F2A91BEAC7991DC7A3FC13DA5F3D9E513C0
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:48]e310: Failed to verify payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to cache payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64
[73DC:2A30][2015-11-18T13:04:48]e314: Failed to cache payload: DotNetVersionManager_x64 from working path: C:\Users\moliv\AppData\Local\Temp\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\DotNetVersionManager_x64, error: 0x80091007.
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i351: Removing cached package: Preparation_Uninstall_ASPNET, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\2b825b3c-fe3f-3e14-b083-a41c0f8d1b22\
[6100:58F4][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i351: Removing cached package: SetupBlocked_Install, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\0cb88b2b-7b82-3890-96ab-deccbbb3a255\
[73DC:367C][2015-11-18T13:04:48]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i352: Removing cached bundle: {5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}\
[6100:5B24][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{5fefbd00-3078-41ea-a615-dbcce6a6f135}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[73DC:367C][2015-11-18T13:04:48]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80091007, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: I got the same issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to fix it by moving to a different folder (desktop in this case)

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1085#issuecomment-157787917

Answer (score 14):

Answered by Damian Edwards in [his comment on the announcement page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/11/18/announcing-net-core-and-asp-net-5-rc.aspx):

> Please note, if you're experiencing an error when trying to install
>   RC1 on Windows "0x80091007 - The hash value is incorrect", delete any
>   previous MSIs for DNVM and ASP.NET VS tooling from the folder you
>   downloaded the RC1 installer to. We're working to fix this issue.

Comment: Or more simply: place the installer alone in a new folder before launching it.

Answer (score 2):

After I moved the loader to a new folder, still no joy. Tried several times with different locations. No luck, same error.

I finally went to the C:\ProgramData\Package Cache folder and found the most recent package (only had one today from my first install attempt). I deleted that.

After that, I was able to use the AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1.exe to successfully install the update.

This seems a lot safer to me than removing all of the Package Cache folder contents. Which I've read will surely impact other aspects of your VS install.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the downloaded file to an empty folder

Answer (score 0):

I've actually solved it by deleting the .dnx folder under my C:\Users\myuser\ and everything from C:\ProgramData\Package Cache

Comment: try also to delete C:\ProgramData\Package Cache

Answer (score 0):

If you run the installer from a folder that contains previous versions of the MSI installers for DNVM (DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi or DotNetVersionManager-x86.msi) or the ASP.NET tools for Visual Studio (WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi or WebToolsExtensionsVWD14.msi), the installer will fail with an error "0x80091007 - The hash value is not correct". To work around this issue, run the installer from a folder that does not contain previous versions of the installer files.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by deleting a folder from C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp. I got the folder name from the below line in the log file.

*Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Temp{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}.be\AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}\AspNet5.ENU.RC1_Update1_KB3137909.exe'*

In this case I deleted {ce3f8ea8-1d35-48c9-a8c2-dd3011cd434b}.

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different problem with the installer, apparently the installer was not able to download the msi installers. But when I followed the links in the logfile I could manually download them. See [question on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1192)

I had to download and manually execute three installers this was, I got all links from the logfile. I restarted the main installer after each manual sub-install and finally the installer ran through.